# Action in Play 2.3 can't find the call function

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3

I'm migrating a working play 2.2.4 project to play 2.3.7. I have an Authenticate annotation that authenticates the user. Problem is it doesn't compile and returns `AuthenticationAction is  not abstract and does not override abstract method call(context) in Action`.

The following code is what i'm running (I've removed the complicated authentication code here (the error still exists whitout it)):

```
public class AuthenticateAction extends Action<Authenticate> {
    @Overrirde
    public F.Promise<SimpleResult> call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
         return delegate.call(ctx);
    }
}

@With(AuthenticatenAction.class)
@RetentionPolicy(Retention.RUNTIME)
public @interface Authenticate {
    String value();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found that in play 2.3 the action's call function uses `Result` and not `SimpleResult`, so switching to `Result` solves the problem.